# Why "catch" block necessarily requres an exception type?

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, runtime-error

In terms of exception handling in java, I have seen that all `try-catch` block needs a type of exception that it has to deal with, more commonly:

```
 catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println("Error occured");
}
```

**Now my question is why it needs `Exception e` as its not used anywhere?**

My ***second question*** regarding the following piece of code I just have written:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 1;

    do {
        try {

            System.out.println(" Enter your first number:");
            int n1 = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(" Enter your second number:");
            int n2 = scanner.nextInt();
            int result = n1 / n2;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("The result is : " + result);
            x = 2;

        } catch (ArithmeticException arithmeticException) {
            System.out.println("Error occured");

        }

    } while (x == 1);

}
```

In the above  piece of code I have seen that the program works with both argument takes as `catch (ArithmeticException arithmeticException)` and `catch(Exception e)`. **So how this two different types of Error can work with the same block of code?**

Comment: exceptions are objects, and your "custom" exceptions are just descendants of that generic exception. **ALL** exceptions can be caught by a generic `catch (Exception e)`, but you can also have MULTIPLE catch blocks, each catching one of the custom ones. e.g. `catch (FailedAssertion e)`, `catch(FileNotFound e)`, blah blah blah.

Comment: You don't need to catch `Exception`, you can catch `Throwable`, which is the superclass of `Exception` and `Error`. However, it should be noted that most `Error`s are not really meant to be caught (e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`); you might want to attempt some sort of cleanup when they occur, but it is usual to rethrow the original `Throwable`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Exception e` parameter is not used in your catch block, but it can be used to display information about the exception that was caught (the exception's message, the stack trace, etc...). You can decide to throw a new type of exception in the catch block, in which case you might pass `e` to the constructor of your new exception.

For example :

```
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

Exceptions are instances of classes, and a catch block with an exception of type X can catch any exception that is of type X or a sub-class of X. Therefore both `catch(Exception e)` and `catch (ArithmeticException arithmeticException)` can catch an `ArithmeticException`. (since `ArithmeticException` is an indirect sub-class of `Exception`).

As Andy commented, you should usually prefer to catch the most specific exception type (`ArithmeticException` in your example), to make sure that you are only catching the exceptions that you meant to catch. For example, in your code `catch (Exception e)` will catch other exceptions too - `NoSuchElementException` and `IllegalStateException` that may be thrown by `scanner.nextInt()`.

Comment: I would add: however, you should catch the most specific exception you can, because otherwise you can unintentionally fail to handle specific exception types which get added to your method signatures as your code evolves (e.g. `InterruptedException`).

Answer (score 0):

This is because `ArithmeticException` is a child of `Exception`. This is a basic principle in object oriented programming (OOP): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

It basically means that `ArithmeticException` is also an `Exception` (well, it inherits from it). But an `Exception` does not have to be an `ArithmeticException`, it could also be an `IllegalArgumentException` or any other child of `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You always `catch` an `Exception` - that is the essence of exception handling, hence the java language requires a `catch` block to catch an `Exception`. Normally, you would want to do something more useful than just printing "Error occured" on the standard output, like throwing your own exception or getting the stacktrace, in which case you would use the `e` object.

About your second question, `Exception` is just a class, with quite a few sub-classes, one of them being `ArithmeticException`. Hence, when you see both `Exception` and `ArithmeticException` working in your catch block, it is just inheritance at work.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you second question. `ArithmeticException` is thrown by `scanner.nextInt()` when it tries to parse something that is not a number such as `one`.

Since `ArithmeticException` inherits from `Exception`, both catch signature are valid to catch the possible `ArithmenticExction`. The catch signature using `Exception` will also catch other errors such as `IOException` and `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

> why it needs Exception e as its not used anywhere?

Because it *should* be used.  That code is effectively ignoring the information about the error and printing out a generic and unhelpful message.  The exception contains information about what happened and is essential in correcting the problem.  It should at the very least be logged somewhere.

> how this two different types of Error can work with the same block of code?

Various operations within a block of code can fail in various ways.  Sometimes it may be necessary to handle on kind of failure differently from another kind.  For example, if a database interaction fails you may want to log the error and notify the DBA and terminate the application entirely, but if an arithmetic error occurs then you may want to notify the developer and return a default value and allow the application to continue.

Understand that *catching* an exception is very different from *handling* an exception.  How the exception is handled (that is, how the system logically responds to the error condition) is entirely up to the logic of the application.  Some errors are recoverable, some are not.  Some imply more significant problems, some do not.  By having multiple `catch` blocks which respond to different types of errors in different ways you can meaningfully handle those different error conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions, lets answer them in correct order.

> **Now my question is why it needs Exception e as its not used anywhere?**

You rised this question, based on bad coding example, This example, even didn't log type of exception, which makes it completely useless in real life scenario.
If you want only log your exception, you should at leas log error message.
Other thing is, you might want different behaviour or you want handle different exception in different places in code. Hence exception type might be very useful.

> **So how this two different types of Error can work with the same block of code**
>   It simple, all exceptions are orgineze in hierarchy, in your case `ArithmeticException` which is thrown by 'nextInt' method extends `Exception`

if you want to see more exception hierarchy, have a look at this picture [image]

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the title question:**

You can use the thrown `e` exception to help you diagnose issues:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Thrown exception: " + e.getMessage());
    //OR, for a custom error
    throw new Exception("Error in try block", e);
}
```

**To answer your second question:**

All exceptions in Java extend from the basic `Exception` type, so having a `catch(Exception e)` will catch all exceptions thrown inside the `try` block.

You can have multiple `catch` blocks to handle different errors:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
    System.out.println("This was an arithmetic exception.");
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("This was an I/O exception.");
}
```

but a generic `catch (Exception e)` won't give you any useful diagnostic data unless you use the thrown `e` exception:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Thrown exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```